# How to determine the total number of rows accessed when reading an EXPLAIN query plan

Tags: mysql

I'm reading the MySQL [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain-output.html) on how to interpret the results of an EXPLAIN plan.  I see the following paragraph at the top:

> EXPLAIN returns a row of information for each table used in the SELECT
> statement. It lists the tables in the output in the order that MySQL
> would read them while processing the statement. This means that MySQL
> reads a row from the first table, then finds a matching row in the
> second table, and then in the third table, and so on. When all tables
> are processed, MySQL outputs the selected columns and backtracks
> through the table list until a table is found for which there are more
> matching rows. The next row is read from this table and the process
> continues with the next table.

If I'm interpreting this correctly, this implies that one can ballpark the worst-case # of rows in the query results by multiplying the quantity found in the "rows" section of each table, since if every row of table 1 could have a row of table 2, etc.

As an illustration, here's a query I'm trying to debug:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DISTINCT roles.id, roles.* 
FROM `roles` 
INNER JOIN `resources` 
ON `resources`.`role_id` = `roles`.`id` 
INNER JOIN `resources` `workspace_resources_roles` 
ON `workspace_resources_roles`.`role_id` = `roles`.`id` 
AND `workspace_resources_roles`.`type` 
IN ('WorkspaceResource') 
INNER JOIN workspaces 
ON resources.subject_id = workspaces.id 
AND resources.subject_type = "Workspace" 
WHERE `roles`.`account_id` = 6804175 
AND `roles`.`deleted_at` IS NULL 
AND `resources`.`type` = 'WorkspaceResource' 
AND `resources`.`user_id` IS NULL 
AND `workspaces`.`archived` = FALSE 
AND `workspaces`.`account_id` = 6804175 
AND `roles`.`id` = 1205685 
ORDER BY roles.name ASC
```

And here's its EXPLAIN plan:

```
id  1
select_type SIMPLE
table   roles
partitions  NULL
type    const
possible_keys   PRIMARY,index_roles_on_account_id_and_deleted_at_and_name,index_roles_on_account_id
key PRIMARY
key_len 4
ref const
rows    1
filtered    100.0
Extra   Using temporary

id  1
select_type SIMPLE
table   resources
partitions  NULL
type    index_merge
possible_keys   index_resources_on_user_id,index_resources_on_role_id,index_resources_on_type,index_resources_on_subject_id_and_subject_type,index_resources_on_subject_id
key index_resources_on_role_id,index_resources_on_user_id
key_len 5,5
ref NULL
rows    4075
filtered    2.5
Extra   Using intersect(index_resources_on_role_id,index_resources_on_user_id); Using where; Distinct

id  1
select_type SIMPLE
table   workspaces
partitions  NULL
type    eq_ref
possible_keys   PRIMARY,index_workspaces_on_account_id
key PRIMARY
key_len 4
ref mavenlink_production.resources.subject_id
rows    1
filtered    5.0
Extra   Using where; Distinct

id  1
select_type SIMPLE
table   workspace_resources_roles
partitions  NULL
type    ref
possible_keys   index_resources_on_role_id,index_resources_on_type
key index_resources_on_role_id
key_len 5
ref const
rows    32620
filtered    50.0
Extra   Using where; Distinct
```

Table 1 has 1 row, table 2 has 4075 rows, table 3 has 1 row, and table 4 has 32,620 rows.  In the worst-case scenario, does this mean a total result set of 1 * 4,075 * 1 * 32,620 = 132,936,500 rows?  If so, that would explain why this query takes 173 seconds in our production environment.

Comment: Provide textual well-formatted codes and outputs, not screenshots.

Comment: @Akina I replaced the screenshot with text.

Comment: Please disable auto-vertical-output client option and show EXPLAIN in table form. Provide CREATE TABLE for all used tables. *If I'm interpreting this correctly* You must take into account that not only joining conditions but WHERE conditions are applied during described scanning process too. And if all rows matches these conditions then you're right - 133kk rows will be investigated. PS. You select the columns from one table only, including its primary key, and apply distinct - in this case WHERE EXISTS is more effective then JOIN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track with interpreting the EXPLAIN. You have a simple query without subqueries, and you are multiplying the `rows` of each joined table together. That's roughly the number of rows to be examined, according to the estimates calculated by the optimizer.

Note the optimizer estimates are pretty rough. Don't think of them as exact.

If you have subqueries, or if you use `LIMIT`, this method of interpreting the rows examined gets more complicated.

If you want a real measurement, not an estimate from EXPLAIN, then execute the query (not using EXPLAIN), and run `SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';`. It will show you a measure of exactly how many operations run by the storage engine. Operations like Handler_read_next or Handler_read_rnd correspond to examined rows. Run `FLUSH STATUS` in between tests to zero out the session status values.